# Table Width 100% with Overflow Scroll

Tags: html, css

I have tables on my web page set to `width:100%`. This stretches the table to the full width of my page if needed, or causes the contents of the table to wrap if the page is too narrow. Everything in the table is kept in a grid.

Unfortunately, some issues arise if there are long words in the table which prevents the td from getting narrower. When this happens, the page starts to developing a horizontal scroll bar to accommodate the table, put other elements on the page, such as paragraphs, stay the width of the original page.

I tried to set the table to `overflow:scroll` to prevent the webpage from getting wider, limiting it to just the table, but this didn't fix the issue. I even tried `overflow:hidden` to see if it would respond, but I couldn't get it to work.

The overflow would work if I set the table to `display:block`, but I can't get the table rows and table data cells to stretch across the full table and maintain its table-like appearance.

Is it possible to always have a table be 100% the width of a page, and to use overflow scroll if the table exceeds this width?

I added this example below. It works nicely except when the page gets very narrow, like around 150px for this example. The table cells get so narrow that it can't wrap any more. I'd like for the table to overflow, but instead the whole page overflows.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra. Fusce sit amet nisi sed ante semper porta non in velit. Aenean euismod finibus nibh id mollis. Duis finibus, urna eu gravida posuere, nisl tortor condimentum dui, sed suscipit ante lacus et augue. Vestibulum ut leo hendrerit, convallis lectus quis, mollis purus. Mauris vitae libero aliquam, porttitor nisi vitae, pellentesque odio. Mauris vestibulum lacinia sem. Aenean sit amet nulla ipsum. Mauris pellentesque dui feugiat odio feugiat, vel egestas eros pellentesque. Cras porttitor metus eu porttitor lacinia.</p>
<table style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;background:#555">
<tr><td>column one</td><td>column two</td><td>column three</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include an example of the code you are having problems with in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Comment: put element with an ellipsis style inside the td

Comment: Maybe [word-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/) is what you're looking for, or the `white-space` property

Comment: did you try `overflow:auto`?

Comment: @FluffyKitten example added. elad I'm not trying to cut off any text, just trying to make the table overflow. Itay and Hisham Bawa, unfortunately it did not resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it by changing `display` alone for the table, but there are a couple of ways you can achieve this.

### **1. Add a "scrolling" container div**

You can up the standard table in a container div and give *it* the `overflow: auto;`, so it will have the scroll bar.

```
table          { width: 100%; }
.scrollwrapper { overflow: auto; }
```

This means the table will stretch to at least 100% of the width even if it is not wide enough on its own, and if the content makes it wider than 100% them the div gets a scrollbar.

**Working Example:**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scrollwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<h3>Scrolling Wrapper - Wide Table</h3>

<div class="scrollwrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
      <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
      <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h3>Scrolling Wrapper - Narrow Table</h3>

<div class="scrollwrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Short text</td>
      <td>Short text</td>
      <td>Short text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### **2. Table with display:block**

This doesn't do what you want, but lets look at why...

When you give the table `display:block` property, it adds the scrollbar to tables if they are wider than the available space, which is what you want. However as you noted, if the table isn't as wide as the available space, `width:100%` doesn't make the columns stretch to fill the width:

**Working Example** of display:block on tables

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<h3>Display:Block - Wide Table</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Display:Block - Narrow Table</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As we can see in the example above, the table is actually stretching to 100%, however because the table row and cells don't fill the table. This is when I discovered the `tbody` hack...

### **3. Table with Display:block and tbody "hack"**

***Note that this is very much a hack and I've no idea how well supported it might be!***

While playing around with this, I realised that the problem is that the rows and cells are not acting as normal rows and cells because they are not in a parent with `display:table`.

That's when I discovered that when I added `display:table` to the `tbody`, it gave the rows and cells a parent with the correct display type and it worked!

```
table       { display: block; overflow: auto; }
table tbody { display: table; width: 100%; }
```

It seems to work even when the `tbody` is not explicitly added in the html.

**Working Example** of tbody hack

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

table tbody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<h3>Tbody "Hack" - Wide Table</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
    <td>thisisoneverylongwordthatwillnotwrapinthetablecell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus nulla et lorem imperdiet, eu malesuada enim viverra.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Tbody "Hack" - Narrow Table</h3>

<table class="tbody-hack">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. And your explanations really helped.

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS grid.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? The overflow will pop in if the width of the table is greater than the width of the `<div>`

```html
<div id="table" style="width:200px">

  <table style="width:100%; overflow:auto;display:block">
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>body</td>
      <td>body</td>
      <td>body</td>
      <td>body</td>
      <td>body</td>
      <td>body</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why `display:block` didnt work for you though

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted you but it wasn't me, though this solution didn't work. It overflows nicely, but it doesn't expand to the full width of the parent div if its wider than the table like if a normal table was set to width:100%.

Comment: Yeah fixed width I can imagine this would work. I have no clue myself why its not working

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact the parent is a container which has flex-grow on it?